# Wildfly 10.0.0 Final does not Log boot logs for deployed application WAR

Tags: logging, log4j, wildfly, log4j2, cas

I have deployed MyApp.EAR and CAS.WAR on wildfly 10.0.0 Final. CAS.WAR uses higher version of Jackson so have used jboss-deployment-structure.xml is used for the same.
So CAS.WAR/META-INF/jboss-deployment-structure.xml looks like,

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2">
<deployment>
<exclusions>
<module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-annotations" />
<module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-core" />
<module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-databind" />
<module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.jackson-jaxrs-json-provider" />
<module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jackson2-provider" />
</exclusions>
</deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Now wildfly 10.0.0 Final is configured to log with log4j. So corresponding log4j.conf file is defined. But on server startup the server console logs stops printing logs once it starts loading cas.war,

Wildfly startup logs,

```
WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "cas.war" (runtime-name: "cas.war")

WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "BankFusion.ear" (runtime-name: "BankFusion.ear")

ISPN000128: Infinispan version: Infinispan 'Mahou' 8.1.0.Final

ISPN000128: Infinispan version: Infinispan 'Mahou' 8.1.0.Final

ISPN000128: Infinispan version: Infinispan 'Mahou' 8.1.0.Final

JBWS022052: Starting JBossWS 5.1.3.Final (Apache CXF 3.1.4)

WFLYSRV0059: Class Path entry xml-apis.jar in /E:/FusionBanking/FBP531.5/WildFly/wildfly-10.0.0.Final/bin/content/cas.war/WEB-INF/lib/serializer-2.7.2.jar does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.

WFLYSRV0059: Class Path entry xercesImpl.jar in /E:/FusionBanking/FBP531.5/WildFly/wildfly-10.0.0.Final/bin/content/cas.war/WEB-INF/lib/xalan-2.7.2.jar does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.

WFLYSRV0059: Class Path entry xml-apis.jar in /E:/FusionBanking/FBP531.5/WildFly/wildfly-10.0.0.Final/bin/content/cas.war/WEB-INF/lib/xalan-2.7.2.jar does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.

WFLYSRV0059: Class Path entry serializer.jar in /E:/FusionBanking/FBP531.5/WildFly/wildfly-10.0.0.Final/bin/content/cas.war/WEB-INF/lib/xalan-2.7.2.jar does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.

WFLYEE0007: Not installing optional component org.springframework.http.server.ServletServerHttpAsyncRequestControl due to an exception (enable DEBUG log level to see the cause)

WFLYEE0007: Not installing optional component org.springframework.web.context.request.async.StandardServletAsyncWebRequest due to an exception (enable DEBUG log level to see the cause)

WFLYWELD0013: Deployment deployment "cas.war" contains CDI annotations but no bean archive was not found. (No beans.xml nor class with bean defining annotations)

2 Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath
```

The log stops in the above line and it does not log the boot information which tell if the WAR is deployed and the server has started, something like,

```
WFLYUT0021: Registered web context: /cas
WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "cas.war" (runtime-name : "cas.war")
WFLYSRV0060: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990/management
WFLYSRV0051: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
WFLYSRV0025: WildFly Full 10.0.0.Final (WildFly Core 2.0.10.Final) started in 27978ms - Started 483 of 772 services (383 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
```

CAS.war inculdes log4j2.xml, does this cause any issue?
log4j2.xml contents,

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!-- Specify the refresh internal in seconds. -->
<Configuration monitorInterval="5" packages="org.apereo.cas.logging">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="baseDir">/etc/cas/logs</Property>
    </Properties>
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d %p [%c] - &lt;%m&gt;%n"/>
        </Console>

        <RollingFile name="file" fileName="${baseDir}/cas.log" append="true"
                     filePattern="${baseDir}/cas-%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH}-%i.log">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%highlight{%d %p [%c] - &lt;%m&gt;}%n"/>
            <Policies>
                <OnStartupTriggeringPolicy />
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10 MB"/>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="5" compressionLevel="9">
                <Delete basePath="${baseDir}" maxDepth="2">
                    <IfFileName glob="*/*.log.gz" />
                    <IfLastModified age="7d" />
                </Delete>
            </DefaultRolloverStrategy>
        </RollingFile>
        <RollingFile name="auditlogfile" fileName="${baseDir}/cas_audit.log" append="true"
                     filePattern="${baseDir}/cas_audit-%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH}-%i.log">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d %p [%c] - %m%n"/>
            <Policies>
                <OnStartupTriggeringPolicy />
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10 MB"/>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="5" compressionLevel="9">
                <Delete basePath="${baseDir}" maxDepth="2">
                    <IfFileName glob="*/*.log.gz" />
                    <IfLastModified age="7d" />
                </Delete>
            </DefaultRolloverStrategy>
        </RollingFile>

        <RollingFile name="perfFileAppender" fileName="${baseDir}/perfStats.log" append="true"
                     filePattern="${baseDir}/perfStats-%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH}-%i.log">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%m%n"/>
            <Policies>
                <OnStartupTriggeringPolicy />
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10 MB"/>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="5" compressionLevel="9">
                <Delete basePath="${baseDir}" maxDepth="2">
                    <IfFileName glob="*/*.log.gz" />
                    <IfLastModified age="7d" />
                </Delete>
            </DefaultRolloverStrategy>
        </RollingFile>

        <CasAppender name="casAudit">
            <AppenderRef ref="auditlogfile" />
        </CasAppender>
        <CasAppender name="casFile">
            <AppenderRef ref="file" />
        </CasAppender>
        <CasAppender name="casConsole">
            <AppenderRef ref="console" />
        </CasAppender>
        <CasAppender name="casPerf">
            <AppenderRef ref="perfFileAppender" />
        </CasAppender>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <AsyncLogger name="com.couchbase" level="off" additivity="false" includeLocation="true">
            <AppenderRef ref="casConsole"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="casFile"/>
        </AsyncLogger>
        <AsyncLogger name="org.apereo.cas.web.CasWebApplication" level="info" additivity="false" includeLocation="true">
            <AppenderRef ref="casConsole"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="casFile"/>
        </AsyncLogger>
        <AsyncLogger name="org.springframework.security" level="off" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="casConsole"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="casFile"/>
        </AsyncLogger>
        <AsyncLogger name="org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security" level="info" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="casConsole"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="casFile"/>
        </AsyncLogger>
        <AsyncLogger name="org.jasig.cas.client" level="info" additivity="false" includeLocation="true">
            <AppenderRef ref="casConsole"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="casFile"/>
        </AsyncLogger>
        <AsyncLogger name="org.apereo" level="info" additivity="false" includeLocation="true">
            <AppenderRef ref="casConsole"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="casFile"/>
        </AsyncLogger>
        <AsyncLogger name="org.apereo.services.persondir" level="off" additivity="false" includeLocation="true">
            <AppenderRef ref="casConsole"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="casFile"/>
        </AsyncLogger>
        <AsyncLogger name="org.apache" level="error" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="casConsole"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="casFile"/>
        </AsyncLogger>
        <AsyncLogger name="org.springframework.cloud" level="info" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="casConsole"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="casFile"/>
        </AsyncLogger>
        <AsyncLogger name="org.springframework.cloud.context" level="off" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="casConsole"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="casFile"/>
        </AsyncLogger>
        <AsyncLogger name="org.springframework.boot" level="off" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="casConsole"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="casFile"/>
        </AsyncLogger>
        <AsyncLogger name="org.springframework" level="off" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="casConsole"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="casFile"/>
        </AsyncLogger>
        <AsyncLogger name="org.springframework.aop" level="off" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="casConsole"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="casFile"/>
        </AsyncLogger>
        <AsyncLogger name="org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure" level="off" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="casConsole"/>
        </AsyncLogger>
        <AsyncLogger name="org.springframework.webflow" level="off" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="casConsole"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="casFile"/>
        </AsyncLogger>
        <AsyncLogger name="org.springframework.session" level="off" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="casConsole"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="casFile"/>
        </AsyncLogger>
        <AsyncLogger name="org.springframework.amqp" level="off" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="casConsole"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="casFile"/>
        </AsyncLogger>
        <AsyncLogger name="org.springframework.integration" level="off" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="casConsole"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="casFile"/>
        </AsyncLogger>
        <AsyncLogger name="org.springframework.messaging" level="off" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="casConsole"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="casFile"/>
        </AsyncLogger>
        <AsyncLogger name="org.springframework.web" level="off" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="casConsole"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="casFile"/>
        </AsyncLogger>
        <AsyncLogger name="org.springframework.orm.jpa" level="off" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="casConsole"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="casFile"/>
        </AsyncLogger>
        <AsyncLogger name="org.springframework.scheduling" level="off" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="casConsole"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="casFile"/>
        </AsyncLogger>
        <AsyncLogger name="org.thymeleaf" level="off" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="casConsole"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="casFile"/>
        </AsyncLogger>
        <AsyncLogger name="org.pac4j" level="off" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="casConsole"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="casFile"/>
        </AsyncLogger>
        <AsyncLogger name="org.opensaml" level="off" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="casConsole"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="casFile"/>
        </AsyncLogger>
        <AsyncLogger name="net.sf.ehcache" level="off" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="casConsole"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="casFile"/>
        </AsyncLogger>
        <AsyncLogger name="com.ryantenney.metrics" level="off" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="console"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="file"/>
        </AsyncLogger>
        <AsyncLogger name="net.jradius" level="off" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="casConsole"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="casFile"/>
        </AsyncLogger>
        <AsyncLogger name="org.openid4java" level="off" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="casConsole"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="casFile"/>
        </AsyncLogger>
        <AsyncLogger name="org.ldaptive" level="off" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="casConsole"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="casFile"/>
        </AsyncLogger>
        <AsyncLogger name="com.hazelcast" level="off" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="casConsole"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="casFile"/>
        </AsyncLogger>
        <AsyncLogger name="org.springframework.context.annotation" level="off" additivity="false" />
        <AsyncLogger name="org.springframework.boot.devtools" level="off" additivity="false" />
        <AsyncLogger name="org.jasig.spring" level="off" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="casConsole"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="casFile"/>
        </AsyncLogger>
        <AsyncLogger name="org.springframework.web.socket" level="off" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="casConsole"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="casFile"/>
        </AsyncLogger>
        <AsyncLogger name="org.apache.cxf" level="off" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="casConsole"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="casFile"/>
        </AsyncLogger>
        <AsyncLogger name="org.apache.http" level="off" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="casConsole"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="casFile"/>
        </AsyncLogger>
        <AsyncLogger name="perfStatsLogger" level="info" additivity="false" includeLocation="true">
            <AppenderRef ref="casPerf"/>
        </AsyncLogger>
        <AsyncLogger name="org.apereo.cas.web.flow" level="info" additivity="true" includeLocation="true">
            <AppenderRef ref="casFile"/>
        </AsyncLogger>
        <AsyncLogger name="org.apereo.inspektr.audit.support" level="info" includeLocation="true">
            <AppenderRef ref="casAudit"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="casFile"/>
        </AsyncLogger>
        <AsyncRoot level="error">
            <AppenderRef ref="casConsole"/>
        </AsyncRoot>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Comment: Are you including log4j in your deployment? What does your log4j configuration look like?

Comment: In standalone.conf of Wildfly have added the argument -Dlog4j.configuration=Sample.log4j.conf. The contents are below,

Comment: log4j.LoggerFactory=org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl
log4j.rootLogger=ERROR,stdout
log4j.logger.com.SampleFile=ERROR,persistenceRoller
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper=ERROR
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.DTDEntityResolver=ERROR
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker=ERROR

Comment: log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t] %5p %c (%F:%L) - %m%n

Comment: Without some kind of reproducer this would be difficult to figure out. If I had to make a guess it's something to do with log4j overriding what's done in the logging subsystem, but that honestly seems like it shouldn't conflict. That pattern though is not the default pattern for the logging subsystem.

Comment: This is the CAS.WAR I was talking about. drive.google.com/drive/folders/…. You can deploy this on Wildfly 10.0.0 Final and make "add-logging-api-dependencies" to "false" in standalone.xml. The issue will get reproduced.

Comment: I've got no idea what the CAS.WAR is :) It's a guess, but I would say something is overriding either logging or taking over System.out.

Comment: CAS.WAR is just another application(https://www.apereo.org/projects/cas) deployed in server deployments folder. SInce you asked for a reproducer I shared the WAR file that can be deployed directly on the server. So what can I check here?

Comment: I don't see a link here to download anything. What you'd want to do is debug the various log managers to see where System.out is going.

Comment: I really can't tell from the code what's going on. There's a lot of "black magic" happening with logging.

Comment: Sorry my bad here is the link https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1XA72lhWKzIIoHnGguPV0h5o4TRchh5Xu?tid=0B_9I7vTCM9PbTUswbzZnTy1nbjQ, and regarding debugging the logmanagers an you guide me the classes to debug

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins, I tried debugging JBOSS code and found that org.jboss.logmanager.LoggerNode.publish(ExtLogRecord) method  is logging the boot informations using org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.ConsoleHandler and org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.PeriodicRotatingFileHandler configured at standalone\configuration\logging.properties. But in case where the application is deployed the record in org.jboss.logmanager.LoggerNode is coming with empty handlers. Can you guide me here?Also this is the link https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1XA72lhWKzIIoHnGguPV0h5o4TRchh5Xu?tid=0B_9I7vTCM9PbTUswbzZnTy1nbjQ

Comment: I don't have permission to the file, but if there is a log4j configuration file in the deployment that could be the cause.

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins Try this link https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1XA72lhWKzIIoHnGguPV0h5o4TRchh5Xu,  Yes it has log4j2.xml on cas.war\WEB-INF\classes\. The contents of the same I have added in defect above.

Comment: I just deployed the app on wildfly-10.1.0.Final and logging seems to work fine for me. It's a bit ugly in that you've got log4j2 writing to `stdout` which is wrapped by a logger for WildFly, but it's definitely still logging.

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins, Please add <add-logging-api-dependencies value="false"/> in standalone\configuration\standalone.xml and try.

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins, we set this file to false as we need to log application specific logs to the rolling file we have configured as part of log4j2.xml. The same is updated above.

Comment: Without know details about how the `CasAppender` works I'm not sure what the issue is. I can say I tried to use a file appender and that file is not created so something is blocking it. Without digging deep into cas I'm not sure what more I can do and I unfortunately can't do that at the moment.

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins, The log4j2.xml which I have added in the issue is writing to the Rolling File which is configured that is not the problem here. Application specific logs after server startup will is getting logged in configured file.

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins, But this loggers should not impact server boot log correct? The problem here is the WILDFLY console not logging the server boot information. As that is the way where people will get to know if service is deployed and WIldfly has started. What I am expecting here is these lines,  WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "cas.war" (runtime-name : "cas.war") and WFLYSRV0025: WildFly Full 10.0.0.Final (WildFly Core 2.0.10.Final) started in 27978ms - Started 483 of 772 services (383 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)

Comment: Yes. Something in there is causing issues. It would take some digging to figure out what it is. There are A LOT of dependencies in the WAR.