# jboss-eap-7.1.0 stops logging serverstartup logs once it starts deploying cas.war of version 5.3.8

Tags: logging, log4j, log4j2, cas, jboss-eap-7

I have deployed CAS 5.3.8 WAR file in JBOSS EAP 7.1.0. But on serverstartup once the JBOSS starts deployment of CAS WAR it stops logging the startup information, Below is the startup log,

```
14:19:30,699 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.6.0.Final-redhat-1
14:19:31,108 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] (main) JBoss MSC version 1.2.7.SP1-redhat-1
14:19:31,258 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYSRV0049: JBoss EAP 7.1.0.GA (WildFly Core 3.0.10.Final-redhat-1) starting
14:19:32,466 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller.management-deprecated] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0028: Attribute 'security-realm' in the resource at address '/core-service=management/management-interface=http-interface' is deprecated, and may be removed in future version. See the attribute description in the output of the read-resource-description operation to learn more about the deprecation.
14:19:32,481 INFO  [org.wildfly.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 22) ELY00001: WildFly Elytron version 1.1.7.Final-redhat-1
14:19:32,483 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller.management-deprecated] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 27) WFLYCTL0028: Attribute 'security-realm' in the resource at address '/subsystem=undertow/server=default-server/https-listener=https' is deprecated, and may be removed in future version. See the attribute description in the output of the read-resource-description operation to learn more about the deprecation.
14:19:33,491 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0039: Creating http management service using socket-binding (management-http)
14:19:33,505 INFO  [org.xnio] (MSC service thread 1-3) XNIO version 3.5.4.Final-redhat-1
14:19:33,511 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] (MSC service thread 1-3) XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.5.4.Final-redhat-1
14:19:33,542 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.io] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 41) WFLYIO001: Worker 'default' has auto-configured to 24 core threads with 192 task threads based on your 12 available processors
14:19:33,547 WARN  [org.jboss.as.txn] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) WFLYTX0013: The node-identifier attribute on the /subsystem=transactions is set to the default value. This is a danger for environments running multiple servers. Please make sure the attribute value is unique.
14:19:33,548 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 50) WFLYNAM0001: Activating Naming Subsystem
14:19:33,558 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jaxrs] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 43) WFLYRS0016: RESTEasy version 3.0.24.Final-redhat-1
14:19:33,560 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 42) WFLYCLINF0001: Activating Infinispan subsystem.
14:19:33,564 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) WFLYWS0002: Activating WebServices Extension
14:19:33,569 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 57) WFLYSEC0002: Activating Security Subsystem
14:19:33,571 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jsf] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 48) WFLYJSF0007: Activated the following JSF Implementations: [main]
14:19:33,575 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYJCA0009: Starting JCA Subsystem (WildFly/IronJacamar 1.4.6.Final-redhat-1)
14:19:33,591 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYSEC0001: Current PicketBox version=5.0.2.Final-redhat-1
14:19:33,602 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 36) WFLYJCA0004: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class org.h2.Driver (version 1.4)
14:19:33,604 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYUT0003: Undertow 1.4.18.Final-redhat-2 starting
14:19:33,621 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYJCA0018: Started Driver service with driver-name = h2
14:19:33,630 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYNAM0003: Starting Naming Service
14:19:33,632 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYMAIL0001: Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
14:19:33,684 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBoss Remoting version 5.0.5.Final-redhat-1
14:19:33,779 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYEJB0481: Strict pool slsb-strict-max-pool is using a max instance size of 192 (per class), which is derived from thread worker pool sizing.
14:19:33,779 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYEJB0482: Strict pool mdb-strict-max-pool is using a max instance size of 48 (per class), which is derived from the number of CPUs on this host.
14:19:33,797 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59) WFLYUT0014: Creating file handler for path 'E:\FusionBanking\POC\CAS538_Upgrade\jboss-eap-7.1.0\jboss-eap-7.1/welcome-content' with options [directory-listing: 'false', follow-symlink: 'false', case-sensitive: 'true', safe-symlink-paths: '[]']
14:19:33,806 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYUT0012: Started server default-server.
14:19:33,808 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYUT0018: Host default-host starting
14:19:33,872 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYUT0006: Undertow HTTP listener default listening on 127.0.0.1:8080
14:19:33,884 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYEJB0493: EJB subsystem suspension complete
14:19:33,967 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYJCA0001: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
14:19:33,974 INFO  [org.jboss.as.patching] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYPAT0050: JBoss EAP cumulative patch ID is: base, one-off patches include: none
14:19:33,989 WARN  [org.jboss.as.domain.management.security] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYDM0111: Keystore E:\FusionBanking\POC\CAS538_Upgrade\jboss-eap-7.1.0\jboss-eap-7.1\standalone\configuration\application.keystore not found, it will be auto generated on first use with a self signed certificate for host localhost
14:19:33,992 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYDS0013: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory E:\FusionBanking\POC\CAS538_Upgrade\jboss-eap-7.1.0\jboss-eap-7.1\standalone\deployments
14:19:34,004 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "cas.war" (runtime-name: "cas.war")
14:19:34,224 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYUT0006: Undertow HTTPS listener https listening on 127.0.0.1:8443
14:19:34,346 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBWS022052: Starting JBossWS 5.1.9.Final-redhat-1 (Apache CXF 3.1.12.redhat-1)
14:19:39,384 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYSRV0003: Could not index class META-INF/versions/9/module-info.class at /E:/FusionBanking/POC/CAS538_Upgrade/jboss-eap-7.1.0/jboss-eap-7.1/bin/content/cas.war/WEB-INF/lib/log4j-api-2.11.0.jar: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unknown tag! pos=4 poolCount = 32
        at org.jboss.jandex.Indexer.processConstantPool(Indexer.java:1417)
        at org.jboss.jandex.Indexer.index(Indexer.java:1451)
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.annotation.ResourceRootIndexer.indexResourceRoot(ResourceRootIndexer.java:99)
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.annotation.AnnotationIndexProcessor.deploy(AnnotationIndexProcessor.java:51)
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:165)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:2032)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1955)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

14:19:41,740 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYSRV0059: Class Path entry xml-apis.jar in /E:/FusionBanking/POC/CAS538_Upgrade/jboss-eap-7.1.0/jboss-eap-7.1/bin/content/cas.war/WEB-INF/lib/serializer-2.7.2.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
14:19:41,757 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYSRV0059: Class Path entry xercesImpl.jar in /E:/FusionBanking/POC/CAS538_Upgrade/jboss-eap-7.1.0/jboss-eap-7.1/bin/content/cas.war/WEB-INF/lib/xalan-2.7.2.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
14:19:41,757 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYSRV0059: Class Path entry xml-apis.jar in /E:/FusionBanking/POC/CAS538_Upgrade/jboss-eap-7.1.0/jboss-eap-7.1/bin/content/cas.war/WEB-INF/lib/xalan-2.7.2.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
14:19:41,757 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYSRV0059: Class Path entry serializer.jar in /E:/FusionBanking/POC/CAS538_Upgrade/jboss-eap-7.1.0/jboss-eap-7.1/bin/content/cas.war/WEB-INF/lib/xalan-2.7.2.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
14:19:43,380 INFO  [org.infinispan.factories.GlobalComponentRegistry] (MSC service thread 1-7) ISPN000128: Infinispan version: Infinispan 'Chakra' 8.2.8.Final-redhat-1
14:19:43,525 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYEE0007: Not installing optional component org.springframework.http.server.ServletServerHttpAsyncRequestControl due to an exception (enable DEBUG log level to see the cause)
14:19:43,526 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYEE0007: Not installing optional component org.springframework.web.context.request.async.StandardServletAsyncWebRequest due to an exception (enable DEBUG log level to see the cause)
14:19:43,587 WARN  [org.jboss.as.jaxrs] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYRS0015: No Servlet declaration found for JAX-RS application.  In cas.war either provide a class that extends javax.ws.rs.core.Application or declare a servlet class in web.xml.
14:19:43,589 WARN  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYWELD0013: Deployment cas.war contains CDI annotations but no bean archive was found (no beans.xml or class with bean defining annotations was present).
14:19:43,769 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) WFLYCLINF0002: Started client-mappings cache from ejb container
14:19:43,895 INFO  [io.undertow.servlet] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 80) 2 Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath
```

After the above line no log is logged into server console. It does not even log startup information like,

14:39:16,270 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0060: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990/management
14:39:16,271 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0051: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
14:39:16,271 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0025: JBoss EAP 7.1.0.GA (WildFly Core 3.0.10.Final-redhat-1) started in 3064ms - Started 292 of 553 services (347 services are lazy, passive or on-demand).

Have set  in standalone.xml. But this should not stop logging startup logs. Here what I see is CAS.WAR has log4j2.xml in its WEB-INF. Does this cause any issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wildfly 10.0.0 Final does not Log boot logs for deployed application WAR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56045262/wildfly-10-0-0-final-does-not-log-boot-logs-for-deployed-application-war)

Comment: This is the CAS.WAR I was talking about. drive.google.com/drive/folders/…. You can deploy this on JBOSS-EAP and make "add-logging-api-dependencies" to "false". The issue will get reproduced.

Comment: Cant say it as duplicate as the other one is for widfly 10.0.0 and there I had another application deployed with CAS.WAR and customized log4j configured. Whereas here only CAS.WAR  is deployed with default logging being kept as is for JBOSS EAP 7.1.

Answer (score 2):

This is the same issue as JANDEX-40 which was reported for the upstream jandex component. We raised JBEAP-15261 for JBoss EAP 7.1.z. This log message won't be logged in the future EAP 7 releases (tentatively EAP 7.1.5 or later).

This is not harmful, so you can ignore this WARN message. However, if you want a workaround to suppress this WARN message, you can manually generate the annotation index and package the generated META-INF/jandex.idx in the problematic jar . Then, the annotation index is not generated for the jar during the deployment.

You can execute the following command to generate the annotation index and package the index in war (using -m option updates the specified jar file to include the annotation index):

```
    java -jar $JBOSS_HOME/modules/system/layers/base/org/jboss/jandex/main/jandex-2.0.2.Final-redhat-1.jar -m log4j-api-2.11.1.jar
```

If you are using EAP 7.1.4 (or later), you can use the following command instead:

```
java -jar $JBOSS_HOME/jboss-modules.jar -mp $JBOSS_HOME/modules/ org.jboss.jandex -m log4j-api-2.11.1.jar
```

Note that the automatic annotation scanning of modules was added to EAP 7 by AS7-944. The current implementation in EAP 7 is an all or nothing. If the index is added to a jar file inside the module, no scanning at all is executed. So, you may need to execute all of jar files which are packaged in your application.

ref : https://access.redhat.com/solutions/3568471

Comment: Hi, in JBOSS we can set per application deployment logging so it will include all Jars which are part of EAR while deployment, so here there is no skip in scanning.